# ASP.NET MVC - Using Oracle With Dapper ORM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, dapper

I have that method:

```
 public User FindBySector(string userId)
    {
        var cn = _context.Database.Connection;

        var sql = @"SELECT Sector FROM AspNetUsers nu where nu.Id = :userId";

        return DbContext.Database.Connection.Query<User>(sql, new { userId }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

I was using sql server, but I will have to switch to oracle.

When performing this search the return is that the table does not exist.

If I search using sql developer it returns what I need, but there I have to put double quotes in the table name and fields, but using dapper it doesn't accept.

Thats the query that work using sql developer

```
SELECT "Sector" FROM "AspNetUsers" where "AspNetUsers"."Id" = 'fab00ef6-cc2d-4021-9562-ff61bff9cdab';
```

How do I replace these double quotes inside the dapper code?

Answer (score 0):

If you ported your sqlserver to oracle and when doing so you wrapped your table names in " " then you kinda let yourself in for a world of pain, because all your table names are now case sensitive in Oracle and you have to supply the " ";

```
SELECT * FROM "AspNetUsers" --returns rows
SELECT * FROM AspNetUsers --becomes ASPNETUSERS and there is no such table
```

You can sort this out(make your life easier) though by renaming them and leaving out the quotes on the to:

```
RENAME "AspNetUsers" TO AspNetUsers
```

Oracle will convert the name to uppercase and will now work in queries no matter what case you specify (omit " ). This will work fine after you rename:

```
SELECT * FROM asPnEtUSerS
```

This will work:

```
SELECT * FROM "ASPNETUSERS"
```

This won't work:

```
SELECT * FROM "asPnEtUSerS"
```

---

If you have hundreds of tables and columns to rename I suggest you write a program that reads from USER_TAB_COLUMNS to list all your columns and programmatically issue renames for all of them. You could also write an sql that writes an sql, perhaps like:

```
SELECT
  'RENAME COLUMN "'||table_name||'"."'||column_name||'" TO '||column_name
FROM user_tab_columns
```

Copy the results of this sql out of the results grid and paste it in again as a query and run it. You might need to add semicolons or something to separate them

Comment: So inside the code there's nothing I can do? Do I have to rename all tables and fields by removing quotation marks? = (

Comment: Well, I suppose you could try `"SELECT * FROM \"AspNetUsers\""` but it's so messy compared to performing a one time op of renaming your columns - it could be done in the time it took to write this comment, and put another way- I'd rather rename all the columns than change all the c# code